# How important are properties file lineendings for Spring?

Tags: java, spring, maven, properties, desktop

I'm using Spring to manage dependency injection and properties for my desktop application. It reads some properties from x.properties files that is not in any archive, but plainly on disk for user convenience. As a precaution I took some steps to make maven take a properties file on build and generate x-win.properties and x-unix.properties with appropriate line endings and permissions, so the end-user would have two files, and program chooses one depending on which platform he/she is on. I made some testing and read the unix file on windows, and I didn't face any problems, which leads me thinking that maybe I'm overengineering and it's pointless hassle, where I could just not care about the lineendings at all. Am I missing something, what are the possible problems I'm facing when ignoring the lineendings completely?

Comment: Try opening the unix file on Windows using Notepad. That will not look good. If you're ok requiring another editor, e.g. Notepad++, then you can go with the unix version, otherwise you need a platform-dependent version of your property file.

Comment: Ah, thanks, that's actually very good point. I used some more advanced editor and it was able to read unix line endings, looks like there really is a problem with notepad, so my current strategy is probably right.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like problems arise with wrong line endings, when using some plain text editors like notepad, so my current building logic looks necessary. Thanks @Andreas